# when connecting to remote desktop connection using kali linux my computer doesnt allow me to connect but xrdp works fine

Tags: kali-linux, remote-desktop

When connecting Kali to a remote desktop connection it connects but when I use remote desktop connection on windows 10 I get an error saying I cannot establish a connection. does anyone know what the problem is?

remote desktop cant connect for the following reasons: 1-remote access to the server is not enabled. 2- the remote computer is turned off. 3-the remote computer is not available on the network. --Make sure that remote access is turned on and connected to the network, and that remote access is enabled. –

Comment: Precise error messages please

Comment: I am on a public network could this be the problem?

Comment: It could be, but unless you give us the details _in your question_ we won't know.

Comment: Please do not put responses in the comments. These are for seeking clarification and not providing it. Instead, [edit your question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/648560/edit) with the missing information

Answer (score 0):

It's likely that you're not running an RDP server on your Kali system.

This is perfectly reasonable because Kali is a specialist distribution used for professional security work such as pentesting. You wouldn't want an RDP service exposing such a system to other devices on a network.